# Javascript element update listener?

Tags: javascript

Say I have two calendar forms that tell me between which two dates I should grab my data from. Is there a way in Javascript to have a listener to check when those two are updated and call a function to pull data again? If I had to use jQuery instead, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please show us what you've already tried, and explain why it didn't work...

Comment: you mean the change event? http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: If your calendar raises an event when updated, it should be possible to listen for it, yes.

Comment: @Robb `change` is only triggered for `:input` elements. Not links (as you'd expect to find in a calendar)...

Comment: My calendar element is a <input type="date"...>, so that change() jQuery function looks great.

Comment: @BenM I was thinking there was at some point an input field getting updated from a date being added or modified.

Comment: @Robb I'm using jQuery change to solve my problem. If you want to post I can accept your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage jQuery's [change](http://api.jquery.com/change) event, assuming you have an `input` field to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the change event like this

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).change(function(){
alert("date1");
});
$( "#datepicker1" ).change(function(){
alert("date2");
});
});
```

working [fiddle to play](http://jsfiddle.net/pPwbf/1/)

Comment: Where did the OP say he was using `datepicker()`?